# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'CodeMirror')

Tags: nextjs

Que tal, me aparece este error únicamente en google con mi cuenta sincronizada; en cambio, cuando pruebo desde otra cuenta sincronizada, desaparece. Muy raro. De paso aprovecho y explico que por alguna razón, algunos get a servicios como google, como puede ser google slides, tardan milenios y salen errores, mientras que en otras cuentas no; quisiera saber si es algún error de caché o algo por el estilo. Gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si está utilizando esta extensión de Chrome: "Blackbox", tienes que desactivarlo.
Para comprobar que funciona. Pruebe en otro navegador como Mozilla, Safari o Edge para asegurarse de que está bien.

Comment: Era eso, muchas gracias!